# Changing the return key to a done key on the iPhone Keyboard (UITextView)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm working on an app with a UITextView. I want to replace the <kbd>return</kbd> key on the keyboard with the <kbd>Done</kbd> key. I've found code for it but then it's for a UITextField and not a UITextView.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the return key with the `returnKeyType` property

```
UITextView *textview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 120.f, 40.f)];

textview.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[self.view addSubview:textview];
```

Regards,
KL94

Comment: I'm getting this one error: expected ',' or ';' before 'initWithFrame'

     What would I need to do to solve this?

Comment: @inFever : I forgot some [ ]. I've edited my response. It should work know.

Comment: Hmm it's still a return key in my project. Would you mind uploading the code to mediafire or something when you got time?

Comment: Maybe are you trying to editing some property of an IBOutlet object ? In that case, don't forget to link your UITextView to your delegate... Try my code in a new project, copy it in the viewDidLoad methods of your viewcontroller it'll work.

Comment: Yeah now I get a done key but but it adds another TextView in the upper left corner. (This is the textview I'm getting the done key in.
And the textview I created still has the normal return key. And yes I did add the delegate and I link the delegate to the text view and the IBOutlet to the text view. Here is the new project i created with the problem: http://www.mediafire.com/?9796p0pu86i1l12
Maybe you know whats wrong.